# Is there a way to disable Angular's double curly brace notation for selected DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

On our website we display user-generated content (blog posts etc.).  It's rendered by a Symfony app.  The frontend is currently being rewritten in the form of an Angular app.  Now we noticed that when a user's blog post contains double curly brace notation, Angular will process it, which is undesired.

Is there a way in Angular to disable the double curly brace parsing for certain DOM elements?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, use the [ng-non-bindable](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngNonBindable) directive. in the element that wraps your dynamic user editable content.

```
<div ng-non-bindable>{{some text}}</div>
```

Comment: Just a note: it seems that you must have an element dedicated to the user content. You can't turn it binding off on the content of the element, while still manipulating the element itself with Angular.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about a direct answer for ignoring interpolation on certain elements but you can change the symbol used if it's in conflict with other data you have:

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$interpolateProvider#endsymbol](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24interpolateProvider#endsymbol)

Comment: Don't think that this is applicable only for some elements. When changed, entire Angular app will use the new interpolation symbol.

Comment: Yes Shidhin Cr's point is correct it looks like James answer is good though I wasn't aware of the directive.