# How to globally add escaping rules to WebForms and Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, razor, webforms

We have a WebForms input field. The value of this input field is set like `textBoxControl.Text = userInputString;`
ASP.NET Html encodes this automatically to prevent XSS, but we also use AngularJS. AngularJS decodes the value and if an Angular template syntax is detected, Angular will compile this.
`test{{4 * 4}}`

This opens up XSS again through Angular Template injection. How can we plug into the WebForms, and Razor Html encoding, to add an extra rule to remove `{{}}` characters. Does WebForms and Razor allow this, or will we need to manually call our own `AngularEncode(x)` method for all user generated values?

Comment: Is using https://stackoverflow.com/a/21558877/34092 an option?

Comment: @mjwills
We have looked at `ng-non-bindable`, but our project is large, spanning multiple years, multiple developers. So instead of putting that directive on all non-angular components, we're looking for a more global solution.

Comment: One approach that might work (that I haven't tried) would be to combine http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/06/using-antixss-as-the-default-encoder-for-asp-net.aspx/ with https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.antixss.antixssencoder.markassafe(v=vs.110).aspx . If you can configure AntiXSS to output { and } as unicode characters that *might* be enough for Angular to not bother 'compiling' them. But you'd need to tesst to be sure.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking at AntiXSS but I can't figure out exactly how to add rules to the whitelist/blacklist

Comment: Maybe start with             AntiXssEncoder.MarkAsSafe(LowerCodeCharts.None, LowerMidCodeCharts.None, MidCodeCharts.None,
                UpperMidCodeCharts.None, UpperCodeCharts.None);

Comment: Did that work @sniels  ?

Comment: @mjwills many parts of the app stopped working when we used AntiXss. Also I don't understand how to use MarkAsSafe. We're probably going to go for ngNonBindable because it's the simplest way.

Comment: That sounds like a sensible approach!